# Ввод данных с клавиатуры без нажатия Enter

Tags: c++

Как можно сделать так,дабы символ в консольке считывался сразу после ввода,без нажатия Enter?Не хочу пользоваться `_getch`,ибо приходится подключать `"conio.h"` для одной только этой функции..Да и она еще в входной поток вставляет '0' после ввода символа.

Comment: Как программа поймёт, что ввод закончен?

Comment: Получен какой-либо символ == ввод закончен